# Ansible run same role multiple times using different variable files

Tags: ansible

Supose I have a server that is used to serve one static website (e.g. `catpics.com`). Using Ansible, I have a `base` role (used to set up firewall, time, user accounts, etc.), a `letsencrypt` role (gets TLS certificates for a website), and a `webserver` role (creates web root directory for a website).

Now I want to host another website (e.g. `snakepics.com`) on this same server. With this new addition, the `base` role still needs to be run once, but the `letsencrypt` and `webserver` roles now need to be run twice. At this point, I have two variable files:

`vars/catpics.com`:

```
---
domain_name: catpics.com
# and other variables...
...
```

`vars/snakepics.com`:

```
---
domain_name: snakepics.com
# and other variables...
...
```

Now that I have these two variable files, how do I run both the `letsencrypt` and  `webserver` roles twice? (once using the `vars/catpics.com` variables file, and once using the `vars/snakepics.com` variables file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use different **[Host Groups](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups)** to make it run for each type and achieve your goal.  There are 2 types of variables for hosts.

- Host Variable which is specific to that individual host that is within a group
- Group Variable which is for that whole host group

inventory / hosts file.

```
[catpics]
catpics.com http_port=301
morecatpics.com http_port=80

[snakepics]
snakepics.com
moresnakepics.com
```

note the `http_port=` is a Host Variable that is inline with the hostname declaration, seperated by a space

then in that same file, using the `host:vars` naming format, you define the Group Variables which is for the **whole group**. So all `snakepics` hosts will have those variables and all `catpics` hosts will have theirs, but keeping their individual Host Variables ie. `http_port=`

```
[snakepics:vars]
FQDN= https://www.snake.com
VAR2= something2

[catpics:vars]
FQDN= https://www.cat.com
VAR2= something2
```

So great, now we've got the hosts setup, we can define what roles are run for each host. The same role will be run

```
- hosts: catpics
  roles:
      - letsencrypt
      - webserver

- hosts: snakepics
  roles:
      - letsencrypt
      - webserver
```

or in this case, hosts could simply look like `- hosts: all` and it will get the vars corresponding to each type of host (snake and cat).

To call the variables is like any other ansible variable fetch `{{ variable_name }}` when running a task in a role:

```
-name: Show how variables like this work
domain_name: "{{ FQDN }}"
some_other_task_variable: "{{VAR2}}"
```

For reference: 
[**Host and Group variables**](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#host-variables)

Now that will solve your issue in the quickest way.  The current [best practice  for using group and host variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html#group-and-host-variables) uses a seperate file  in the `group_vars/*role_name_file*` directory to automatically fetch all the variables for each Host Group

Comment: Thank you! Any clues on how to arrange the hosts file such that the `base` role is only run once?

Comment: Where will that base role be run exactly? Is it pointing to a server that the other hosts are each pointing to? You either make it run on `- hosts: all` so it runs on each host, or you run it once pointing to another server/vm that each host have been configured to point to

Comment: `catpics.com` and `snakepics.com` are on the same physical server. `base` needs to be run once on that physical server.

Comment: yeah so give the physical server its own host group `[physical-server]` and run the `base` role for the physical server to that, just like we did when running  `letsencrypt` and `webserver` on the hostgroups `[catpics]` and `[snakepics]`